# mysql stored procedure for search from identical tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, innodb

Hi developers I am researching  ways of fast selecting rows from many tables with identical structure. Tables have too much data to be 1 table. So every table contains data for 1 month.
For example log_2011_01 ,log_2011_02 etc.  Tables have datetime column `created_at`.

I need to create stored procedure , it must contain 2 datetime parameters for searching between this dates and few others.

Now I see next realization:
 stored procedure must calculate collection of tables between 2 dates and generate sql to select data with union_all . 
I think I will be to heavy and not ready for highload,isn't it?
Is there are any other possibilities to do this?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you should have used a partitioned table instead of separate tables per month.  Are you aware of and have you considered using range partitioning by date?

Comment: @Fivell: Just curious, how much is "too much" ?

Comment: @ypercube: I have no Idea how much it now maybe 5-10 GB but size will grow  about 10x time per next year

Comment: OK, 5-10 GB per month is quite a lot.

Comment: @searlea: partitioned tables can't be used because of some limitations that it has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with other comments, but I tried to help you with SP. This SP builds the query that can be executed with [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
-- SP definition:

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE iterateMonths(IN fromDate DATE, IN toDate   DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE tempDate DATE;
  DECLARE query    VARCHAR(1000); -- Query string, length might be increased

  SET tempDate = fromDate - INTERVAL (dayofmonth(fromDate) - 1) DAY;

  WHILE tempDate <= toDate
  DO

    IF query IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET query = concat(query, '\r\nUNION ALL\r\n');
    ELSE
      SET query = '';
    END IF;

    SET query = concat(query, 'SELECT * FROM log_', DATE_FORMAT(tempDate, '%Y_%m'));
    SET tempDate = tempDate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
  END WHILE;

  SELECT query; -- Output generated query
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

-- Call the SP

SET @fromDate = '2010-07-29';
SET @toDate = '2011-08-29';
CALL iterateMonths(@fromDate, @toDate);

-- Output:

SELECT * FROM log_2010_07
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2010_08
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2010_09
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2010_10
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2010_11
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2010_12
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_01
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_02
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_03
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_04
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_05
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_06
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_07
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_2011_08
```

Answer (score 0):

No alternative to stored procedure here. Highload will be there considering the structure of your tables.